# Clonar selects dependientes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un código en el que me clona la primer fila de una tabla, tengo dos `select`uno dependiente del otro, es decir dependiendo de lo que yo seleccione en el primer `select`(`TIPO_ACTIVIDAD`), me listara unas opciones en el segundo(`SUBTIPO`), el clona bien, aunque no copia los `select`, y las opciones se despliegan bien, solo si es la primer fila, y es ese el problema, cuando clono una fila, y voy a seleccionar una de las opciones del primer `select` bien. pero cuando voy seleccionar la del segundo me llama las opciones del `select` de la fila superior, no se que hacer pues se que si clona la fila clona, estos son los códigos:

**JS**

Código para clonar primera fila

```
<script>

$(function(){
// Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de 
la tabla
      $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
      $("#tabla tbody 
      tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila-fija').appendTo("#tabla");
});
// Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
$(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
   var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
   $(parent).remove();
    });
});

</script>
```

Código para mostrar Selects dependientes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function cargarSUBTIPO(valor) {
   var arrayValores=new Array( 
     new Array("Arreglos","Arreglo Bidireccional","Arreglo Bidireccional"), 
     new Array("Arreglos","Arreglo Pymes","Arreglo Pymes"),
     new Array("Arreglos","VT Mejoramiento Servicio","VT Mejoramiento 
     Servicio"),
     new Array("Desconexiones","Desconexion Carta","Desconexion Carta"),
     new Array("Desconexiones","Desconexion x ","Desconexion x") 

   );

  if(valor==0) {

         .getElementById("SUBTIPO").disabled=true; 

  }else{

     document.getElementById("SUBTIPO").options.length=0; 
     document.getElementById("SUBTIPO").options[0]=new 
     Option("Seleccione...", "Seleccione...");

     for(i=0;i<arrayValores.length;i++) {

       if(arrayValores[i][0]==valor) {       
          document.getElementById("SUBTIPO").options
          [document.getElementById("SUBTIPO").options.length]
          =new Option(arrayValores[i][2], arrayValores[i][1]); 
       } 
     }

    document.getElementById("SUBTIPO").disabled=false;

   } 
} 

function seleccionado_SUBTIPO(value) {
  var v1 = document.getElementById("TIPO_ACTIVIDAD"); 
  var valor1 = v1.options[v1.selectedIndex].value; 
  var text1 = v1.options[v1.selectedIndex].text; 
  var v2 = document.getElementById("SUBTIPO"); 
  var valor2 = v2.options[v2.selectedIndex].value; 
  var text2 = v2.options[v2.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<td>
  <select name="TIPO_ACTIVIDAD[]" id="TIPO_ACTIVIDAD" 
    onchange='cargarSUBTIPO(this.value);'>
  <option value="">Selecciones...</option>
  <option value="Arreglos">Arreglos</option>
  <option value="Desconexiones">Desconexiones</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Eso es por que no puedes seleccionar tus `select` por el `id`, si el `id` se repite el sistema siempre va a coger el primero que encuentre, además en las buenas prácticas del `html` si vas a tener varios elementos con el mismo nombre es mejor usar una `class` ya que un `id` debe ser un identificador único he irrepetible.
2. Para que te funcione correctamente debes seleccionar es el `select` con el cual se está haciendo la interacción del usuario, eso lo logras con el `this`, cuando haces `onchange='cargarSUBTIPO(this.value);` no envíes `this.value` envía únicamente `this` es decir todo el elemento como tal, luego recorres los nodos hasta llegar al siguiente `select` perteneciente a la fila actual

**EJEMPLO**

```
function cargarSUBTIPO(elemento) {
    var valor = elemento.value;

    var arrayValores=new Array( 
    new Array("Arreglos","Arreglo Bidireccional","Arreglo Bidireccional"), 
 new Array("Arreglos","Arreglo Pymes","Arreglo Pymes"),
 new Array("Arreglos","VT Mejoramiento Servicio","VT Mejoramiento 
 Servicio"),
 new Array("Desconexiones","Desconexion Carta","Desconexion Carta"),
 new Array("Desconexiones","Desconexion x ","Desconexion x") 
    ); 

    var select_subtipo = elemento.parentElement.parentElement.children[5].children[0];

    if(valor==0) { 
    // desactivamos el segundo select 
    select_subtipo.disabled=true; 
    }else{ 
    // eliminamos todos los posibles valores que contenga el SUBTIPO 
    select_subtipo.options.length=0; 
    // añadimos los nuevos valores al SUBTIPO 
    select_subtipo.options[0]=new Option("Seleccione...", "Seleccione..."); 

    for(i=0;i<arrayValores.length;i++) { 
    //unicamente añadimos las opciones que pertenecen al id seleccionado del primer select 
    if(arrayValores[i][0]==valor) { 
    select_subtipo.options[select_subtipo.options.length]=new Option(arrayValores[i][2], arrayValores[i][1]); 
    } 
    } 
    //habilitamos el segundo select 
    select_subtipo.disabled=false; 
    } 
}
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Hola Camilo Vazquez, realice lo que dijiste pero persiste el error, lo coloque asi: onchange='cargarSUBTIPO(this);

Comment: Tienes que cambiar tu código, la forma en que recibes el parámetro en la función, recuerda que ya no estás recibiendo un valor si no todo el elemento

Comment: Te agradecería si me pudieras dar una idea de como tendría que quedar en código, la verdad no se mucho de js

Comment: Te voy a editar la funcion del onchange en la respuesta para que veas !

Comment: Ya te la edité, prueba así, te debería de funcionar

Comment: Hola mira que llama a los elementos bien cuando selecciono cada opción, pero no me deja activar el segundo `select`

Comment: Cuando se debería activar el segundo select?

Comment: al seleccionar una opción del primero, se tiene que activar y me tiene que mostrar las opciones segun elección del primero.

Comment: Y antes te funcionaba? es que en tu código no veo en que momento seleccionas un select diferente o en que momento llamas a esta función seleccionado_SUBTIPO()

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66736/discussion-between-camilo-vasquez-and-andersson-viveros-martinez).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, excelente!!!